# How to let user change iphone app theme?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, lookup

I have `Article` and `Category` entities that have a many to many relationship. `Category` has a `name` and a `imagePath` (which keep its name and path to image of an icon for that category).

With this model I can show article with category name (and image of category) it belongs.

**Problem**

If I want to let user change category image (for example change theme with a new pack of icon) what should I do?

What I'm thinking now is create separate entity, called `ThemeItem`, which keep `categoryId` (need to add that to category) and move `imagePath` from `Category` to this `ThemeItem` entity, so it would become

```
Article <<------------>> Category  
- text                   - categoryId
                         - name
- categories(Relation)   - articles(Relation
```

and

```
Theme   <-->> ThemeItem
-themeId      -categoryId
-themeName    -imagePath
              -theme(Relation)
```

With this approach I will keep let user select theme via settings interface and keep `themeId` in `NSUserDefaults`

Any thing I should concern with this or there is a better way of doing this kind of thing?

**Retrieve image**

With new model I only got `categoryId` from `Category`, so I have to look up in `ThemeItem` to get `imagePath`. Here is some `NSPredicate` I think of

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThemeItem" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryId == %@ AND theme.themeId = %@", category_id_for_article, theme_id_from_user_defaults];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

with this predicate I got `ThemeItem` and its `imagePath`

Comment: Could you explain this *with this approach I have to keep the selected Theme in NSUserDefault and lookup with categoryId every time I need an image.*? I think you could do it only with Category entity. Explain better your goal because it's not very clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: I add more detail in edited part of my post.

Comment: Where can I find *themeId*? Then, could you explain the semantic of *Theme*, *Category* and *Article*? Thanks

Comment: ThemeId would be hard code for now (Don't know this is a right way of doing this). Article is belongs to Category and one Category can have several Article, so I made this many-to-many relation, but Theme is just a look up table and would be pre-populate readonly data (no relation with anyone).

Comment: Ok, but there is no *themeId* in your model!

Comment: Sorry :( my bad it should be in `Theme`, edited the post.

Comment: The request could not work. I think you have to set up 2 different requests, but I can't understand what your goal is. You save the theme but you need to fetch the Category and then return to Theme. I missed something... Could you try to edit your question? What do you save in NSUserDefaults? What do you want to retrieve? Theme, Category or Article objects? Maybe I could help you.

Comment: Edited the post (add ThemeItem and Theme). My goal is let the user change image icon of category from my predefined themes. Users retrieve articles and category of the article as usual, but to retrieve image I need an extra step to get it from `Theme`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11373/discussion-between-art-and-flex-addicted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need to grab all the `ThemeItem` objects that belong to a specific theme (the one chosen in user settings) and to the current `Category`. Is it right?

If so, you are in the right track. The query you are performing is ok.

Now, in my opinion, you could have problems if you delete a `Theme` and its `ThemeItem`. In this case you can have a `Category` that is not "linked" to any `ThemeItem`. In other words, for that `Category` you have no `ThemeItem`.

Here you have two choices.

1) Delete manually `Categorie`s that are not linked anymore with a `ThemeItem`

2) or create a relationships (a one-to-many I suppose) between `ThemeItem` and `Category` (you don't need a `categoryId` anymore). From `ThemeItem` to `Category` use a Cascade Rule and use Nullify for the inverse. When you delete a `ThemeItem` the `Category` is deleted too.
Since cascade rules, if not managed properly, are dangerous (they can delete the entire db), you need to test how they behave.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

If you want, you can create a relationships between `ThemeItem` and `Category`. For example call it `categories`:

Your model could be like the following:

```
ThemeItem                   Category
- categories (rel)  <-->>   - themeItem (inverse rel)
```

Relationship `categories` is a one-to-many rel to `Category` with a cascade rule. `themeItem` is a one-to-one inverse relationship to `ThemeItem` with a nullify rule.

When you delete a `ThemeItem` object, the `Categorie`s object are deleted too. On the contrary, when you delete a `Category`, the `ThemeItem` object (that its linked with that `Category`) removes the specific `Category` form its children.

In this manner you can avoid maintain graph integrity in your model.

Obviously these new relationships can be applied to your model in this situations:

- the user delete a `ThemeItem` and you want to delete `Category`s linked with it
- a `Category` belongs to a specific `ThemeItem`; in other words, each `Category` is contained in a specific `ThemeItem`

I suggest you to read about [Relationships on Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).

A note: There is no a correct way to create a model. The main aspect that, in my opinion, is important when dealing with Core Data is performance. When you use Core Data you deal with objects and not with row data. Said this, accomodate your model to fit this aspect.

I hope this anwser will let you to decide the right model to fit your problem. Cheers.

Comment: Yes that what I want to do. On first run I will have seed data for Category and Theme, user may add and delete there own category, but can't touch my seed data. If I choose second choice how do I change Theme ? I have no way to know which ThemeItem bind to which Category ?

Comment: @art Do you want to know how to link a *ThemeItem* with a *Category*?

Comment: With second choice yes. With former one I can pre populate app with predefine theme and mapping between ThemeItem and Category with categoryId, but with the new one I have no clue of how to do it.

Comment: @art Since I'm a bit busy with work I added an edit to my answer. I hope it will help you to find the right solution to your problem. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I really appreciate it, but with this model user have to change the icon manually after select new Theme. I want all image in that category to change to that Theme. Btw I will accept this answer and I will update the answer if I come up with anything better, Thanks.